# Java reading from file problem

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I have a file, let's call it text.txt. It contains a few lines of text. I am trying to read this in with my code so that I can edit it using my code, unfortunately whenever I try and read it, it simply returns null, and does not load the code at all. No error message or anything.

An example is a file with the following in it :

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

when loaded, it loads the following :

```
a
b
c
d
null
```

Which makes no sense to me whatsoever, since, if it is entering the while loop, it shouldn't be exiting! Can anyone help me out please ?

```
try
{
     File theFile = new File(docName);

     if (theFile.exists() && theFile.canRead())
     {  
        BufferedReader docFile;
        docFile = new BufferedReader(
              new FileReader(f));

        String aLine = docFile.readLine();

        while (aLine != null)
        {  
           aLine = docFile.readLine();
           doc.add( aLine );
        }

        docFile.close();
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are reading the first line with

```
String aLine = docFile.readLine();
```

and then you discard this line by doing

```
aLine = docFile.readLine();
```

inside the loop.

Comment: Not to mention that he adds aLine to doc *before* checking if it's null.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line before reading the next line.  If you think about this logically, it should make sense, and if not, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( (aLine = docFile.readLine())!= null)
{  
     doc.add( aLine );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop, if you flip the two statements, then it will add the line you know is not null, then check the next line.  The way you have it now, the loop checks the line, then advances a line and adds the new one to doc, so it can be null, then exit after adding null.